# Setting Oracle_home in enviroment variables

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms, oracle-xe

I have ORACLEXE  and ORACLE forms & reports 11g installed.

If I set the `ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server`

My ORACLEXE would work and oracle forms will not work

> (error:oracle image startup failure).

If I set the `ORACLE_HOME = C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_FRHome1`

My Oracle forms would work and ORACLEXE will not work

> (error: c:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_FRHome1\forms\fmcus.msb missing).

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Environment variable `ORACLE_HOME` is not relevant in Windows.

In this [documentation 9.2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/win.920/a95490/orahome.htm#1006117) Oracle states:

> Oracle Corporation recommends that you never set the ORACLE_HOME
>   environment variable, because it is not required for Oracle products
>   to function properly. If you set the ORACLE_HOME environment variable,
>   then Oracle Universal Installer will unset it for you.

In newer Oracle client release `ORACLE_HOME` environment variable is not mentioned anymore in Windows installation guides.

However, I don't know whether this statement is also valid for Oracle Forms.

You should also check your `PATH` settings, I assume there is the problem.

Comment: thank you! I'll surely check. But without ORACLE_HOME in environment variable both of them are not working.